# Package protected access modifyier with dot containing scope name

Tags: scala

In Scala, there is a special type of access modifiers: protected[enclosing_scope]. But as soon as I try to use it with package names containing dots, like protected[framework.ui] i get "']' expected but '.' found" compiler error.

It seems really strange, since it is conventional to use dots in package/namespace names in java/.net. Do I miss something or is it impossible to use this access modifier with this type of scope names.

**Update**

I accepted an answer as it was relevant, though it seems impossible to make what I wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only restrict the visibility to a scope that you are in, so what do you need dots for?

If you are in

```
package foo.bar
```

you can make sth.

```
private[foo]
```

and

```
private[bar]
```

What is your use-case for the dots?

Comment: There could be a possible `package foo.bar.foo`…

Comment: @Debilski So what is the problem with this packages?

Comment: @om-nom-nom You cannot distinguish between `*private[_root_.foo]` and `*private[_root_.foo.bar.foo]` unless this syntax is allowed.

Comment: @Debilski Ha-ha, rare scenario, but yes, it looks like a breach in Scala specification. You must be really good at making boundary condition test cases